# select elements within one column according to a value from another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a new learner of R. Currently, I am working on some infinium 450k data. I have some data like this:

```
IlmnID        | RefGene_Location                                               | RefGene_Name
------------- | ---------------------------------------------------------------| ----------------------------------------------
cg27656579    | Body;5'UTR;5'UTR;5'UTR                                         | MIR5096;GNG4;GNG4;GNG4 
cg03503114    | TSS1500;1stExon;1stExon;5'UTR;1stExon;5'UTR;5'UTR;5'UTR;1stExon| CAPZA1;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L
```

The elements in RefGene_Location columns are corresponding to the genes in RefGene_Name columns. What I want is retaining genes that correspond to "5'UTR", "1stExon" and "TSS1500", but not "Body". Finally, compile them into 
results like this:

```
IlmnID      | RefGene_Name
----------- | ------------
cg27656579  | GNG4
cg03503114  | CAPZA1
cg03503114  | ST7L
```

Comment: How many variables (columns) does your data have?

Comment: try to give us a sample of your data, you can do `dput(your_data[1:10,])` and copy paste the results here.

Comment: I have attached my sample data above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyverse` package. First split and unnest the columns. Filter and remove duplicates.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(-ID), funs(strsplit(., ';'))) %>% 
 unnest() %>% 
 filter(loc1 %in% v1) %>% 
 select(-loc1) %>% 
 unique()
```

Which gives,

> ```
>   ID  name1
> 1  A   GNG4
> 4  B CAPZA1
> 5  B   ST7L
> ```

**Where,**

```
v1 <- c("5'UTR", "1stExon" ,"TSS1500")

df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B"), loc1 = c("Body;5'UTR;5'UTR;5'UTR", 
"TSS1500;1stExon;1stExon;5'UTR;1stExon;5'UTR;5'UTR;5'UTR;1stExon"
), name1 = c("MIR5096;GNG4;GNG4;GNG4", "CAPZA1;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L;ST7L"
)), .Names = c("ID", "loc1", "name1"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It solves my problem perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

To do this, we're going to try three simple stages.

**Stage 1:** row selection

First, we'll select rows in the dataframe where `RefGene_Location` contains all three phrases `5'UTR`, `1stExon` and `TSS1500`, but not the phrase `Body`. I'll suppose the dataframe you're working with is called `df

```
df <- df[all(c("5'UTR", "1stExond", "TSS1500") %in% df$RefGene_Location) & 
         !"Body" %in% df$RefGene_Location, ]
```

**Stage 2:** gene names

Now we want to grab the gene names from the `RefGene_Name` column. I'm going to assume that the name always occurs in the text after the last `;` in that column, and replace the `RefGene_Name` column with this entry.

```
# Split df$RefGene_Name into chunks separated by ";", and keep the last chunk
df$RefGene_Name <- sapply(strsplit(df$RefGene_Name, ";"), function(x) x[length(x)])
```

**Stage 3:** get rid of excess columns

This is just so the data is in the same format as you gave in your question. There are other columns in your dataset we no longer need, like RefGene_Location, so we'll remove these.

```
# Keep the two columns "IlmnID" and "RefGene_Name"
df <- df[, c("IlmnID", "RefGene_Name")]
```